# vba to move multiple rows of data per unique id into set number of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm hoping someone can help with this query please. I have multiple rows of data per employee and I need to move the data onto one row per employee.

Data looks like this: There may be up to 4 rows of data per employee but not always:

person id, person name, location, start date, end date, amount 1, amount 2, total

I need to get each row of data onto one row, can anyone suggest best way to do this please?

Comment: What did you try? Edit your Q (don't add it as a comment) and add your code.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have, what you want and what you've tried.